# MacOS-like OCR for Linux?

Tags: linux, gnome, ocr

How can one setup the same ubiquitous OCR capabilities on Linux, in a manner similar to how one can copy text from *any image* in *any software* on MacOS and iOS?

I am using EndevourOS with Gnome DE.

Comment: Please explain what features you need. Most people here won't be familiar with macOS or even iOS, so we would need to know more about what you need.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.  Roll it back if I destroyed it's  meaning.

Comment: So iOS has a feature that automatically converts images to text via OCR?

Comment: "Any software" probably means the Apple ecosystem apps, like the default image/PDF viewer. The OCR appears "everywhere" if you stick with Apple. Other apps, like Evince, Firefox, LibreOffice Draw, GIMP, etc. don't do it for you automatically even on MacOS. You are looking for a set of applications supporting automatic OCR in your use cases, not an OS-wide feature. I don't know of any. I use gImageReader to extract text from images. There is an ancient feature request for GNOME's document viewer: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/31 But I found none for the image viewer.